# Перенаправление запроса

Tags: .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте! Стоит задача перевода сайта со статических страниц на динамические, генерируемые по статическим URL одним и темже скриптом php. Но дело в том, что база данных будет заполняться постепенно и поэтому хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы в том случае, если на сайте есть статическая страница, соответствующая запросу, то пользователю возвращалась она, а в других случаях происходило обращение к новому общему скрипту генерации страниц. Не подскажете, как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете есть ли файл и если перенаправяете на index.php к примеру

```
RewriteMode on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#не файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#не директория
RewriteRule (.*)/? index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```